# a marginal text that contains a subscripted number in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how I can add an `mtext()` or a `text()` that can say: `Note: CG[10] stands for central gravity`? (of course, `[10]` is the subscript of CG.)

I'm trying the **following `mtext()`** but can't get the desired outcome:

```
plot(1:10, ty="n", ann=F)

mtext("Note:", bquote(bold(CG[10])), side = 1, line = 1, adj = 0, cex = 1.2, font = 2)
```

Comment: usually use paste and expression together. I find sprintf and parse to be easier `plot(1, main = parse(text = sprintf('"Note: "*%s*" stands for central gravity"', 'CG[10]')))` being easier to generalize and/or automate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a simple way is to use `expression` and `*` sign to separate the subscripted from ordinary (i.e., non-subscripted) text. So, in my case, this will be:

```
mtext(expression("Note: "*bold(CG[10])*" stand for Central Gravity"), side = 1, line = -5, adj = 0, cex = 1.2, font = 2)
```

And the desired outcome is:

[image]